# When wrap test with a new "describe" section

Tags: protractor

I'm starting with Protractor and I would like to know when it's recommendable to wrap a bunch of test in a new describe section.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We group tests by functionality (user story) in a seperate file. Each file has it's own describe section. We use page object to reuse testcode and increase maintainability.

http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings